# create array with two different data types. convert into HashMap, TreeMap, LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, arrays, collections, converters, typeconverter

How to create arrays:

{int, String}, {String, String}, {int, long}, {String,boolean}, {String, double}, {int, class Car}, {String, class Car}

This is class Car:

```
public class Car {
    int id;
    String car_name;
    String number;

    public Car(int id, String car_name, String number) {
        this.id = id;
        this.car_name = car_name;
        this.number = number;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Car{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", car_name='" + car_name + '\'' +
                ", number='" + number + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

And. How to convert by custom method that into HashMap, TreeMap,  LinkedHashMap ?

Comment: It's totally unclear to understand. Can you please rephrase ?

Comment: Create array with two data types. Example: {int, String}. There is int (primitive data type) and String. How to create this array ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't create an array for different data types. As per documents,

> An array is a container object that holds a fixed number of values of a single type. The length of an array is established when the array is created. After creation, its length is fixed.

You can use Hashtable or HashMap for your need.

```
//Code to put entries in Hashtable
Hashtable<String, Object> car = new Hashtable<>();
car.put("id", id);
car.put("car_name", car_name);
car.put("number", number);

//Code to retrieve data from Hashtable
int id = (int)car.get("id");
String car_name = (String)car.get("car_name");
String number = (String)car.get("number");
```